# feature weight learning algorithm in classfication

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I am working in a multi-classification task. I have successfully used Neural network(2 hidden layers) and Support Vector Machines(SVM) to do this. However, I want the actual weights assigned to each of the features.

As both SVM and NN does not explicitly produce weights, is there any way to compute them??

I guess logistic regression wont work as the feature space is high(around 20+ features) and the problem is non-linear. Correct me if I am wrong.

Suggest if any other classification algorithm can give me the weights and have performance similar to NN/SVM.

```
Feature Space
x1,x2,x3........................... x25   --- class1
x1,x2,x3........................... x25   --- class2
x1,x2,x3........................... x25   --- class3
```

The features belong to different domains such as (text, scroll move, time spent, no of images/links etc)

After classification, I want to understand how each feature is weighted during classification??

Comment: Why do you want weights? And what do you mean by weights?

Comment: At the end  after successful classification, I want to understand what is the importance of each feature. Lets say in logistic regression or simple perceptron, we finally converge to a specific theta value for each feature. In a way a feature with high theta value correspond to higher importance. I want something similar in high dimension non-linear classification  problem.

Comment: You really need to state why you need to know importance of features. Different techniques may serve better in different circumstances. In fact, normally it is not separate features, but rather subsets of features that influence result the most. E.g. if you have features `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, and you have found that they are sorted by importance as `x1` > `x2` > `x3` (the most important is `x1`, the least important is `x3`), it is still possible that `x2` and `x3` together are more important than `x1` and `x2` (one case for this is that `x1` and `x2` may highly correlated).

Comment: @ffriend: Here is the detail description of the problem. I am working on a multi-application based classification. I have different features from different applications(A1, A2, A3).
E.g A1  - x1 x2 x3 x4...
    A2  - x16 x17 x18 x19...
    A3  - x26 x27 x28 ......
Now my task is to classify a document based on the attributes collected from all these features from 3 applications. Now what I really want to understand is the importance of each application. I thought understanding of weights of feature will help in deciding that. I am ready for any other suggestion.

Comment: Ah,now I see. So you want to measure importance of applications/sets of features. In this case I agree with Slater's idea of removing specific sets of features and measuring classification results.

Answer (score 2):

"Weights" is an extremely vague term when it comes to machine learning problems, and could be used in many contexts.

If you're already using an NN, and want to know how much each feature contributes to the classification efficacy of the Neural Net, measure the net performance with a given feature removed and weight based on the reduction in performance.

If you just want a general idea of which features are more important you should definitely run logistic regression. It in fact is not at all constrained to linear problems. (I'm guessing you got this idea from the picture on the wikipedia article, but that's just a logo if you will of the entire regression series.)

Also in the world of machine learning 20+ features is generally considered to be minuscule. A large number of features would be several thousand.

Comment: Agreed - 20 features you could almost do by hand ;-)

Comment: Thanks @slater. Removing a given feature and measuring weight based on reduction in performance is a good idea. In that case, the reduction performance in total network error will make more sense or reduction in precission/recall/F1 value?? Any already published work in mapping the reduction to weights??

Comment: I agree that 20+ feature is a small feature space in machine learning world. I also understand that logistic regression can be used for non-linear classification problems with polynomial approach. However, I the feature space increase exponentially if we add 3/4 degrees of polynomial with 20 features. Is it still recommended to do Logistic regression with 20+ features?? N.B: The decision boundary is highly non-linear(confirmed with PCA on 2 dimensions) .Sometimes it is very difficult to differentiate between boundaries for all 5 classes.

Comment: @alex I'm not sure you understand what logistic regression is. Specifically it is logistic, meaning it is not linear, not polynomial, but a logistic curve.

Comment: @alex since the concept of weights here is totally arbitrary, the choice in which performance metric you use is also arbitrary. Choose whichever you care most about. And no, finding "weights" is not a subject that academics write papers about.

Comment: Logistic regression is commonly understood as a linear model/linear classifier because while the logit function is nonlinear---f(x+delta) is not a linear increase in f(x)---the decision surface is linear in the feature space (\sum_i w_i.x_i).

Comment: And logistic regression should be robust to large feature spaces (millions of features), it's a convex optimisation problem, and most sensible optimisers won't try to compute the Hessian but use something like LBFGS, or even stochastic gradient descent

Comment: Thanks @BenAllison slater for your explanation. Sorry if I was not clear earlier. What I meant was, to identify non-linear boundaries, the logistic function uses the parameter in polynomial feature space.
    h(x) = g(Theta0+theta1*x1+theta2*x2+theta3*x1^2+theta4*x2^2....)
    where g= logistic/sigmoid function
Thus I thought with more features, it will very explode. But as you guys point out Logistic Regression is robust to large feature space(millions!!) I will implement Logistic regression in that case.

Comment: I have another follow up question. As I explained in the above , my ultimate goal to determine to the weight/importance of each application(consisting of many features) in a classification task.
(A1, A2, A3). E.g A1 - x1 x2 x3 x4... 
A2 - x16 x17 x18 x19... 
A3 - x26 x27 x28 ......

So If logistic regression finds the weight for x1,x2....x1^2 x2^2.. x1*x2.... How can map them back to corresponding application ??

Comment: This is why I suggested using your actual model rather than fitting a logistic regression model. Since your predictions aren't done using logistic regression, you can't interpret the coefficients in a logistic regression, or their p values, for the purposes of your model.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your neural net probabilistic in its output---use a softmax output layer and minimize cross entropy loss---you can evaluate the likelihood of the training data or some heldout data. This allows you to compare different models with a common evaluation measure which is intrinsic to the model, in the same way as you would with logistic regression (although you won't be able to do standard significance tests on the weights).

The issue with using logistic regression to compute these meaningfulness scores is that the model of the data implicit in the statistic is not the model of the data used to actually predict, and thus they're not really telling you anything about your model.

Honestly though, I would say using the evaluation metric you actually care about is the correct thing to do. If you really need a significance test, I would have thought you could do some bootstrapping/resampling/MCMC based scheme to compute p values or intervals.

Answer (score 0):

```
After classification, I want to understand how each feature is weighted during classification??
```

I am not sure want do you mean by saying during classification. If I understand well the comment,*`removing specific sets of features and measuring classification results`*, added by `ffriend` illuminate the situation. But I think you can weight your feature without doing any classification. Remember `PCA`. You extract a sequence of eigenvalues and based on their magnitude you keep the corresponding eigenvectors. With the same logic you can use all the eigenvalues as weights. Be careful with the correspondence between yous data and the corresponding eigenvalues.

I hope that I am not out of the scope of that question.

Thank you.